# Change text of Input button after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following input HTML tag

```
<input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary start" autocomplete="off" onclick="submitForm();" />
```

When I click on the submit button, it goes to the related JavaScript file and executes the function submitForm();

I would like to change the text of the submit form to "Please wait..." until the function is completed.

Is there a way this can be done?

This is how the submitForm() function looks like:

```
function submitForm() {
        $("#submitForm").val("Please wait...");
        if (formValidation() === true) {
            submitFormInfo().done(function () {
                $("#submitForm").val("Submit");
            });
        }
}

function submitFormInfo() {
return $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "URLHERE"
        error: function (xhr) {

        },
        success: function (result) {
        },
        async: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure, find the element by ID and set its value attribute. You may also want to disable the element to avoid double submit.

Comment: have you tried anything? How does your `submitForm()` looks like?

Comment: Here is the thing... when I do that, it doesn't change the value because the button freezes until the submit form is fully completed. Seems like the JS thread is blocked and the name does not change.

Comment: @user3587624 then the real problem is your submitForm method which seems to be blocking instead of being asynchronous.

Comment: Added some extra code that hopefully will help :)

Comment: Set `async: true` in your Ajax call.

Comment: If I set it to true, then the form will reload because the code runs asynchronously and it doesn't wait until the execution is completed. Maybe I am doing something completely wrong on the development of the app. I am pretty new using JS :)

Comment: You *want* it to be asynchronous so that it doesn't block other processing (including repainting the button with the updated text), but also you should prevent the default form submission so that you just do the Ajax. You could add `return false` to the end of the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused... what onsubmit attribute are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery please see:-

https://jsfiddle.net/swawrm1g/3/

I have removed:-

```
onclick="submitForm();"
```

and added:-

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
    $(this).val('Please Wait...');
    submitForm()
});

function submitForm() {
    alert('Form submitted');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you having asynchronus operation in submitform() ?
if yes then you can use following line

```
$("#submitForm").val("Please Wait");
```

Comment: Here is the thing... when I do that, it doesn't change the value because the button freezes until the submit form is fully completed. Seems like the JS thread is blocked and the name does not change.

Comment: Can you share code you have on submitForm() ? i am sure you must be having normal post back and not an asynchrons call which does not freeze the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `beforeSend` option on your ajax call, so in your `submitForm()` function, you can do something like this:

```
function submitForm() {
  var submitForm = $("#submitForm");
  if (formValidation() === true) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "URLHERE",
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        data: { somedata: 'here' },
        beforeSend: function (){
            submitForm.val("Please wait...").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        },
        success: function (data){
            // do something
        },
        error: function (){
            // do something
        },
        complete: function () {
            // regardless of the response status (success/error) 
            // the codes below will be executed.
            submitForm.val("Submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple javascript is enough to do this..

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
  document.getElementById('submitForm').value="Please wait..";
}
</script>
<input type="submit" id="submitForm" onclick="submitForm()" value="Submit">
```